# Conflicto con pull request en rama erronea

Tags: javascript, github, git-commit, github-desktop

soy bastante nuevo en GitHub y en un proyecto realice un pull request a la rama principal en vez de a la rama de desarrollo. Este Pull Request está esperando ser revisado pero ¿ Cómo lo elimino para poder realizarlo en la rama correcta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes ir a la pestaña de *pull requests*, seleccionar tu *pull request* y presionar el botón *close pull request*.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes encontrar la información completa en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.github.com/es/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/closing-a-pull-request).

Comment: Gracias amigo! casi me da un infarto cuando me di cuenta jaja